# Extract text, hyphen and number from string

Tags: c#, string-matching

In work we use a Global Distribution System for bookings which is very very old, when we cancel a booking we get a response from their web service to say if the booking has been successfully cancelled.

The response contains a bool to say if it is cancelled or not and a string with any other info such as cancellation reference or why it could not be cancelled etc etc.

If it is successfully cancellled the cancellation reference is tied up in the middle of the string within the response and looks something like this

```
"NXT REPLACES  1  REDISPLAY ITINERARY1CXL-13113654 THANK YOU FOR YOUR INTEREST"
```

From this string I need to extract "CXL-13113654"...

Basically the CXL followed by the "-" then any character upto but not including the " "

I have searched university of google and everything I can find seems to be only extracting numbers, characters or symbols never a mixture within a set format like mine.

Can anyone help?

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you looking for a regex pattern or a utility to extract the string? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: RegEx would be the obvious answer to this, though it could also be accomplished using less than elegant string parsing. Find the offset to the dash, subtract 3, find the next space, and do a substring. If the CXL is *always* "CXL" then it you could save a couple steps

Comment: Regex was the option I was looking at but I'm not very good with Regex as I have tried to learn it but I really struggle. One other option i have tried to do is write an algorythm that find the CXL- then takes every char and break when I find " " but I can not get that working yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex pattern:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(inputString, @"(?<match>CXL\-[^\s]+)").Groups["match"].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a single line search... you'll want a Regex like this....

```
(?<Anything>[^CXL[\s]*\-[\s]*[^\s]+)
```

This looks for CXL followed by white-space of any amount (0 or more), then a hyphen, then 0 or more whitespace, and then match all non whitespace. All of this will be put into the group called "Anything". [You can test it on this page if you like](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

The C# for this would then be...

```
// -- in using statements add this
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// -- in your code add something like this

var inputString = "NXT REPLACES  1  REDISPLAY ITINERARY1CXL-13113654 THANK YOU FOR YOUR INTEREST";
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"(?<Anything>CXL[\s]*\-[\s]*[^\s]+) ");
if(match.success && match.Groups["Anything"].Success)
{
  var anything = match.Groups["Anything"].Value;
  // -- do something with anything
}
```

Comment: Updated... sorry didn't through a code around it and it was not showing some of the regex

Comment: the chars after the CXL- could be any character not just a number, this will only work for numbers

Comment: So would my expressiion be: 
Regex.Match(text, @"CXL[\s]*\-[\s]*(?<Anything>[^\s]+)");

Comment: This works in the sense that it extracts the number so thank you very much for that but it doesnt include "CXL-".

Comment: Oh, just move teh Group over then... I updated the code and added the C# to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "NXT REPLACES 1 REDISPLAY ITINERARY1CXL-13113654 THANK YOU FOR YOUR INTEREST";
        var match = Regex.Match(input, @"CXL\-(?<number>\d+)\s+");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["number"]);
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
13113654
```